# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in Resources.Designer.vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm programming a DataGridView based Windows-Forms-Application with an imagecolumn. It basicly just displays entrys out of a database. The following code is used for displaying the Image (used to be working):

```
            for each row as datarow in dt.rows

                'Some code ....
              With gridRow                    

                'Picture
                If row.Item("img_ID").ToString = "0" Then
                    .Cells(0).Value = Nothing
                ElseIf row.Item("img_ID").ToString = "1" Then
                    .Cells(0).Value = My.Resources.icon11
                ElseIf row.Item("img_ID").ToString = "2" Then
                    .Cells(0).Value = My.Resources.icon2__2_
                Else
                    .Cells(0).Value = Nothing
                End If

                ' Some Other Code 
              End With
            Next
```

This code causes en Error in `Resources.Designer.vb`

[image]

The additional Information Part in Google-Translator-English:

(Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.)

A call destination has caused an exception error.

How do i fix it?

Using the following:

```
    Friend ReadOnly Property icon11() As System.Drawing.Icon
        Get
            Try

                Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("icon11", resourceCulture)
                Return CType(obj, System.Drawing.Icon)
            Catch ex As Exception
                My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(ex.Message & vbNewLine & "- - - - - " & vbNewLine & ex.InnerException.Message)

            End Try
        End Get
    End Property
```

Got me the following (translation by Google again):

(Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.)

A call destination has caused an exception error.

---

(Der Vorgang wurde erfolgreich beendet.)

The operation was successful

Nice try Mr. InnerException..

---

**The Answer**: by Hans Passant

> You must show the stack trace of the inner exception. Do keep in mind that your code is flawed, every time you use the My.Resources.iconxxx property you get a new icon. That needs to be disposed. That works about ten thousand times and then the OS stops you from creating more icons and the weirdo error messages start to happen. Use such a property only once, it can be assigned multiple times. And give the user a break, nobody likes to have to claw through thousands of rows. Look at the way Google displays a million query hits.

The exact problem was solved the following way:

```
                private ico() As System.Drawing.Icon = New System.Drawing.Icon() {My.Resources.icon11, My.Resources.icon2__2_}
                'Some Code
                If row.Item("img_ID").ToString = "0" Then
                    .Cells(0).Value = Nothing
                ElseIf row.Item("img_ID").ToString = "1" Then
                    .Cells(0).Value = ico(0)
                ElseIf row.Item("img_ID").ToString = "2" Then
                    .Cells(0).Value = ico(1)
                Else
                    .Cells(0).Value = Nothing
                End If
```

Comment: Do you have something in the `InnerException` property? `TargetInvocationException` is a general exception that indicate that the invoked method via reflection thrown an error.

Comment: Let me give it a look! Guess its ex.innerException? - - - Going to Edit into Topic

Comment: You must show the stack trace of the inner exception.  Do keep in mind that your code is flawed, every time you use the My.Resources.iconxxx property you get a *new* icon.  That needs to be disposed.  That works about ten thousand times and then the OS stops you from creating more icons and the weirdo error messages start to happen.  Use such a property only once, it can be assigned multiple times.  And give the user a break, nobody likes to have to claw through thousands of rows.  Look at the way Google displays a million query hits.